# Confused about TextAppearance style in app compat v21

Tags: android, android-theme

When I'm using `appcompat v21` with `Light.DarkActionBar` theme in my app I have:

If I'm using `?android:textAppearanceMedium` my text has **greyish** color

If I'm using `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium` my text has **black** color

What is the difference between those two? I thought they, by definition, should be the same, the second being simply more explicit expression of the first?

Comment: not sure if related but maybe this will be somehow helpful http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Comment: @deadfish it's an overview, it doesn't address any specific issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theme attribute `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` is set by the current theme to point to a style resource. On Theme and Theme.Light, it points to `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium`. On Theme.AppCompat themes, it points to `@android:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium`.

So when you explicitly point to `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium` when your app is targeting Theme.AppCompat, you are getting the text appearance style meant for Gingerbread-themed apps. If you use `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` instead, you will get a style meant for your current theme.

Comment: Why there is:@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium

Comment: That's the pre-Honeycomb style that the textAppearanceMedium theme attribute points to by default in Theme and Theme.Light. Generally you would want to use the theme attribute instead to stay consistent with your activity theme.